# Is it efficient to lookup text files in a directory using a hashTable?

Tags: java, hashtable

In terms of space and runtime would using a hash table to search for a particular file in a directory be efficient? I want to create the index once and when you want, be able to reindex when needed but be able to search relatively fast.

I store the hashCode as the key and the filename as the value.

```
private Map<Integer,String> indexDirectoryByHash()
{
    Map<Integer,String> hashTable = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
    File directory = new File(this.path);
    File[] directoryFiles = directory.listFiles();


    String filename;
    int hashCode;



    for (int i = 0; i < directoryFiles.length; i++)
    {
        filename = directoryFiles[i].getName();
        hashCode = filename.hashCode();
        hashTable.put(hashCode,filename);
    }

    return hashTable;
}





public boolean searchFile(String filename)
{

    if (hash.get(filename.hashCode()) != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Okay changed it to use a set instead of hashtable.

```
private Set<String> indexDirectoryByHashSet()
{
    Set<String> files = new HashSet<String>();
    File directory = new File(this.path);
    File[] directoryFiles = directory.listFiles();

    String filename;

    for (int i = 0; i < directoryFiles.length; i++)
    {
        filename = directoryFiles[i].getName();
        files.add(filename);
    }

    return files;
}

public boolean searchFile(String filename)
{
    return fileSet.contains(filename);
}
```

Comment: A hashCode is not a unique identifier. Just use a Set<String> to store the file names. That's all you need to know if a filename exists or not.

Comment: I strongly urge you not to use `Hashtable`. It's been obsolescent for nearly nineteen years, and carries cruft that predates and isn't part of the Java collections framework. Use one of the replacement `Map` implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fast, but incorrect: since it stores hash, and because hash is not unique, your search method runs a risk of returning false positive.

You can't fix this by adding a check that whatever is returned from the map matches the search name, because of hash collision.

A better approach is to store Strings instead of hash codes. Use HashSet of Strings for that, and check by calling contains(name) method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason not to, don't really over think it, just code what is efficient today, if it turns out to be inefficient then look for an alternative.